# How many hostnames can be supported by a wildcard ssl certificate? Is there any limit?

Tags: tls, wildcard

How many hostnames can be supported by a wildcard ssl certificate? Is there any limit ?

Answer (score 40):

There are two distinct things here. One is about the number of hostnames that you can put in a certificate. The other is the notion of "wildcard names".

In the [Subject Alt Names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6) extension, you can put "alternate names" of type `dNSName`. Each of them is an "acceptable server name" (i.e. clients will accept the certificate for a server that purportedly uses that name). The ASN.1 notation for the extension is the following:

```
   SubjectAltName ::= GeneralNames

   GeneralNames ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF GeneralName

   GeneralName ::= CHOICE {
        otherName                       [0]     OtherName,
        rfc822Name                      [1]     IA5String,
        dNSName                         [2]     IA5String,
        x400Address                     [3]     ORAddress,
        directoryName                   [4]     Name,
        ediPartyName                    [5]     EDIPartyName,
        uniformResourceIdentifier       [6]     IA5String,
        iPAddress                       [7]     OCTET STRING,
        registeredID                    [8]     OBJECT IDENTIFIER }
```

See the "MAX" ? It means "no limit". You can put as many names as you want in a certificate.

Well, since we are talking about DER encoding, the total length of the certificate must not exceed 702223880805592151456759840151962786569522257399338504974336254522393264865238137237142489540654437582500444843247630303354647534431314931612685275935445798350655833690880801860555545317367555154113605281582053784524026102900245630757473088050106395169337932361665227499793929447186391815763110662594625664 bytes, and each name will take a dozen bytes or so (at least). But existing libraries and protocols are likely to enforce stricter limitations. For instance, if the certificate is to be used in SSL/TLS (e.g. a certificate for a Web server that does HTTPS), then the certificate MUST fit within 16 megabytes (its length is encoded in a three-byte field, as per the [SSL/TLS protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2)). Thus, you can have a maximum of about **one million alternate names** in a certificate.

Then, each of the name may be a **wildcard name**, meaning that it contains the "*" character. The "*" will match any sequence of characters except dots. Existing browsers, there again, enforce other constraints, in particular:

- There shall be only one "*" character in the name (so no "`*.*.stackexchange.com`", to take an actual case).
- The "*" must appear as first character, not elsewhere (so no "`meta.*.stackexchange.com`", to continue on that real-life situation).
- The "*" must stand for a complete name component (hence "`*.example.com`" but not "`*foo.example.com`").

A name component is limited to 63 characters, and the characters must be only letters (case insensitive), digits and the minus sign ("-"), so there are about 37<sup>64</sup>-2 = 23169162752708970943114627382699355445603465075569066753527132965271355336698663689946873706000418559 possible names matching a wildcard name (the "-2" is because the empty string is not a valid name component)(there are other restrictions, e.g. not beginning with a minus sign, but clients tend not to enforce these).

Since you can have a million alternate names in a certificate, multiply that number by one million, and you will have the maximum number of host names that match your "wildcard certificate". It ought to be enough for most purposes.

---

**Take note** of a common confusion. We say "wildcard certificate" but that is a misnomer. What is meant is "certificate such that at least one of the contained names is a wildcard name".

For a real-life example, have a look at Google's certificate (connect to `https://www.google.com/`, then ask your browser to show the certificate). Right now, the returned certificate contains no less than **49 alternate names** which are the following:

```
*.google.com
*.android.com
*.appengine.google.com
*.cloud.google.com
*.google-analytics.com
*.google.ca
*.google.cl
*.google.co.in
*.google.co.jp
*.google.co.uk
*.google.com.ar
*.google.com.au
*.google.com.br
*.google.com.co
*.google.com.mx
*.google.com.tr
*.google.com.vn
*.google.de
*.google.es
*.google.fr
*.google.hu
*.google.it
*.google.nl
*.google.pl
*.google.pt
*.googleadapis.com
*.googleapis.cn
*.googlecommerce.com
*.googlevideo.com
*.gstatic.cn
*.gstatic.com
*.gvt1.com
*.gvt2.com
*.urchin.com
*.url.google.com
*.youtube-nocookie.com
*.youtube.com
*.youtubeeducation.com
*.ytimg.com
android.com
g.co
goo.gl
google-analytics.com
google.com
googlecommerce.com
urchin.com
youtu.be
youtube.com
youtubeeducation.com
```

Notice that 39 of these names are "wildcard". With the numbers above, this means that this certificate can potentially match no less than 903597347355649866781470467925274862378535137947193603387558185645582858131247883907928074534016323811 distinct host names. And that's *Google* -- one can expect that their certificate "works everywhere".

Comment: Just to save work of others trying to figure out how is the maximum length of BER/DER encoded data determined. Maximum size of the number indicating the length is 127 bytes so the maximum length stored there is 2^(127*8) = 2^1016. See [Length octects - The definite form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#The_definite_form) on Wikipedia.

Comment: ... BUT you have to subtract 1 because in 1016 bits, the biggest integer you can encode is 2^1016-1. AND then you have to add the length for the header (1 byte for the 0x30 tag, and 128 bytes for the encoding of the length).

Comment: Note also that, stricto sensu, only the TBSCertificate is DER-encoded; the complete certificate structure may use BER with an indefinite length. However not many implementations support that. Moreover, the SAN extension is in the TBSCertificate.

Comment: I suspect you could potentially have a few more if you include [international domain names](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5890#section-4.2). In addition, your third bullet point ("*The "\*" must stand for a complete name component*" doesn't seem quite right according to [RFC 6125](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#section-6.4.3), "*The client MAY match a presented identifier in which the wildcard character is not the only character of the label*".

Comment: @Bruno: it should be tested. RFC 2818 certainly allows wildcards to match partial names, but I am not sure deployed clients (Web browsers) actually support that. RFC 6125 lists it as a "may", which means that you cannot really count on it being universally supported.

Answer (score 7):

A wildcard certificate matches a pattern, not a hostname or set of hostnames.   It's issues to `*.example.com`, meaning any host of format `[subdomain].example.com` will match.   It is notable perhaps, that it is limited to a single level so the `*.example.com` wildcard cert could be used for `sub1.example.com` and `sub2.example.com`, but not `deeper.sub1.example.com`.

So, since the match is based on pattern rather than hostnames, there is no limit, and there would be no way to generically enforce a limit, given that you can use the cert in many places, none of which need know about the others, or all of the specific hostnames it's being used for.

Comment: Thanks Xander. How about SAN ? Is there any limit ? Can we use wildcard while defining the hostnames?

Comment: @Arun There might not be theoretical limits regarding the number of SAN entries you can have, but there will certainly be practical ones: they will make the certificate bigger, which will certainly slow down the handshake, or even stop it from completing successfully. I've seen certain TLS stacks "choke" when using `certificate_authorities` lists (in on a `Certificate Request` message) that are too long, I would suspect the same would happen with a server certificate that has just become too big.

Answer (score 1):

As per **Certificate authority** Guideline, Wildcard SSL certificate is only supported for security of single level sub-domains with the same host name.

Without any limit Wildcard SSL can secure unlimited single level sub-domains.

Comment: What reference is "*Certificate authority Guideline*" exactly?